# Automatically refactor objects from Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I read that you should not normally use setFrame when you are using autolayout.

However, if I have a constraint from a UIButton to a UITextView, lets say the UITextView's height changes and in the IB I set the UIButton's constraint to be 10 vertical unit spacings apart from the UITextView. When I change the UITextView's height by using setFrame, is there anyway to get the UIButton to automatically recalculate it's y position based on the constraint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't modify the view's frame when using autolayout. You need to modifiy the constraint, wether by resetting it programmatically or by adding an IBOutlet that references the constraint and modify its constant value.
You might want to take a look at [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/03/things-you-need-to-know-about-cocoa-autolayout/)

Comment: thank you, I was just wondering if it was possible. I am trying to incorporate autolayout into an app that was written prior to autolayout and was hoping I could use sort of hybrid.

Comment: I should clarify then... it can be done, but you might find sometimes some unpredictable results. The best course of action is to embrace autolayout fully.